# cordova plugin development: How to change native code?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm completly new to cordova plugin development, so I need some help to get started. My plan is to modify the camera plugin for iOS and Android https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera and I followed the steps described here: https://gist.github.com/mlynch/c9a469948680979a8740d68c47d1cf98

So what I did was to clone the plugin github project to my machine. Then I 
added the local project to my angular project:

```
cordova plugin add --link ~/path/to/plugin
```

and 'installed' it to my project so now my package.json says

```
 "cordova-plugin-camera": "/path/to/plugin",
```

everything is working so if I take a picture it is displayed in my app.

Now the fun part should begin - but I see no changes if I update my Objective-C code. Even if I comment out the whole class. 
So I think I'm missing something and I assume that my Objective-C code doesn't get compiled.

What do I have to do?

By the way: I use ionic DevApp to test my app. Maybe that's the reason so the app uses internal plugins that come with the app?

Comment: Jep the DevApp is the reason you see no changes. The DevApp supports the most common plugins which have their native code compiled and packaged in the DevApp. If you change native code now it will not make its way into the DevApp. Only the contents of the `www` folder are available.